# Expo Proxy not working : Redirect URI not getting changed

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth, google-signin

I  am having difficulty in using Google Oauth Client, since, i think my expo proxy is not working, due to which the redirect URI cannot be setup.

```
// screens/LoginScreen.js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import { auth } from '../config/firebaseConfig';
import * as AuthSession from 'expo-auth-session';


export default function LoginScreen() {
    const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({ useProxy: true });
    console.log("Redirect URI:", redirectUri);
    const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
        clientId: process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      }, redirectUri);
      useEffect(() => {
        if (response?.type === 'success') {
          const { id_token } = response.params;
          const credential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
          auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        }
      }, [response]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button disabled={!request} title="Login with Google" onPress={() => {console.log(redirectUri);promptAsync()}} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    },
  });
```

When I print the redirect URI, it shows to an IP which I cannot give to redirect URI field of Google OAuth Client. Why does this happen?

Have tried everything mentioned in other forums and have used help from ChatGPT too.

Comment: you need a static port or it wont work with google oauth